# Kotlin calculator using double data type

Tags: android, kotlin, math, types

I am learning Kotlin and can't seem to make sense of the different data types. I have a simple calculator app that currently adds or subtracts whole integers.

I am trying to make it possible to use "." to also calculate decimals. I've tried a number of things to convert the number to Double and don't think I am understanding the data types properly. I can get it to work explicitly with integers.

The closest I got to double was working but it automatically appended a zero after the decimal

```
package com.example.calctest

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

enum class CalculatorMode {
    None,Add,Subtract
}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var lastButtonMode = false
    var currentMode = CalculatorMode.None
    var labelString = ""
    var savedNum = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setupCalculator()
    }

    fun setupCalculator() {
        val buttons = arrayOf(button_zero, button_1, button_2, button_3, button_4, button_5, button_6, button_7, button_8, button_9)
        for(i in buttons.indices) {
            buttons[i].setOnClickListener { calcNum(i) }
        }
        button_dot.setOnClickListener { calcDecimal() }
        button_addition.setOnClickListener { changeMode(CalculatorMode.Add) }
        button_subtraction.setOnClickListener { changeMode(CalculatorMode.Subtract) }
        button_equals.setOnClickListener { calcEqual() }
        button_clear.setOnClickListener { calcClear() }
    }

    fun calcEqual() {
        if (lastButtonMode) {
            return
        }

        val labelInt = labelString.toInt()

        when(currentMode) {
            CalculatorMode.Add -> savedNum += labelInt
            CalculatorMode.Subtract -> savedNum -= labelInt
            CalculatorMode.None -> return
        }

        currentMode = CalculatorMode.None
        labelString = "$savedNum"
        updateNumString()
        lastButtonMode = true
    }

    fun calcClear() {
        lastButtonMode = false
        currentMode = CalculatorMode.None
        labelString = ""
        savedNum = 0
        textView.text = "0"
    }

    fun updateNumString() {
        val labelInt = labelString.toInt()
        labelString = labelInt.toString()

        if(currentMode == CalculatorMode.None) {
            savedNum = labelInt
        }

        textView.text = labelString
    }

    fun changeMode(mode: CalculatorMode) {
        if(savedNum == 0) {
            return
        }
        currentMode = mode
        lastButtonMode = true
    }

    fun calcNum(num: Int) {
        val strVal = num.toString()

        if (lastButtonMode) {
            lastButtonMode = false
            labelString = "0"
        }

        labelString = "$labelString$strVal"
        updateNumString()
    }

    fun calcDecimal() {
        if(labelString.contains(".")) {
            return
        } else {
            labelString = "$labelString."
        }
        val labelDouble = labelString.toDouble()
        labelString = labelDouble.toString()
        textView.text = labelString
    }

}
```

Comment: Double.toString() is for quick logging of numbers, like to help with debugging. It doesn’t give you any control over how the number looks. You should use String.format() to control number formatting for the user to see. That said, you should probably use BigDecimal for a calculator app or you’re going to be fighting with precision issues trying to support integers and decimals both.

Comment: Thanks, I've read that BigDecimal is immutable and can't find a way to change my code to utilize this - do you have any pointers to somewhere I can read up on this more? Not making much sense of this..

Comment: Doubles and Ints are immutable too. That just means you can’t change its internal state. When you operate on a number, you get a new number that is not the same instance of a class that you had before.

Comment: Managed to figure out a solution, I'll post here in a bit, thanks!

Comment: bigdecimal and toDouble did the trick